# Integration Problem (Ordinary Differential Equations)

Tags: calculus

\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left[k(x_2-x_1)^2+k(x_1-x_0)^2\right]\,dx_1
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left[2kx_1^2+kx_1(-2x_2-2x_0)\right.\\
&\qquad\qquad\left.+k(x_2^2+x_0^2)\right]\,dx_1\tag 8\\
&=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{\sqrt 2\sqrt k}\exp\left[\frac{k}{2}(x_2-x_0)^2\right]\tag 9
\end{align*}
[Source.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TR7tY.png)

I can't get from (8) to (9). Why does the x1 disappears?

Comment: Hint: evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} dx$

Comment: It is a well-known result that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} dx=\sqrt{\pi}$. You have to use Fubini and polar coordinates for that.

Comment: First, complete the square and then change variable to get get something looking like $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2} dy$. $x_1$ disappears because it is the integration variable and the bounds are used; so, no more $x_1$ in any result whatever the bounds could be.

Comment: can you post the original problem please?

Comment: Source: http://web.mit.edu/dvp/www/Work/8.06/dvp-8.06-paper.pdf                    The equation 8 is incorrect from the paper and I tweaked it to the correct one as shown above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete the square to get
$$k(x_2-x_1)^2+k(x_1-x_0)^2 = 2k\left(x_1^2-x_1(x_2+x_0)+\frac{x_2^2+x_0^2}2\right)=2k\left(
\left(x_1-\frac{x_2+x_0}{2}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{x_2+x_0}{2} \right)^2
+\frac{x_2^2+x_0^2}2
\right)=2k\left(
\left(x_1-\frac{x_2+x_0}{2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{x_2-x_0}{2} \right)^2
\right)
$$
Substitute into integral to get
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left[k(x_2-x_1)^2+k(x_1-x_0)^2\right]\,dx_1
=\\
\exp\left[ \frac{k}{2}(x_2-x_0)^2 \right]\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left[2k\left(x_1-\frac{x_2+x_0}{2}\right)^2\right]\,dx_1
\underset{k=-q<0\\ \alpha =\sqrt{2q}\left(x_1-\frac{x_2+x_0}{2}\right)\\d\alpha= \sqrt{2q}dx}{=}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2q}}\exp\left[ \frac{k}{2}(x_2-x_0)^2 \right]\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\alpha^2}\,d\alpha
=\\\frac{\sqrt\pi}{\sqrt {-2k}}\exp\left[\frac{k}{2}(x_2-x_0)^2\right]
$$